# Speeding up Azure Storage API with NET4 and .NET 4.5 Parallel Extensions

Tags: asp.net, stream, threadpool, task-parallel-library, azure-storage

The .NET 4 and 4.5 whitepapers have comments about how the parallel library can speed up performance of IO access. (example of a buffered serial queue below)

[image]

**Question:**

Has anyone successfully integrated .NET 4 parallel buffering, or .NET 4.5 [Async/Await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) with Azure storage?

If so, what has the impact been on the ThreadPool, and would it be advantageous to have this run outside of the threadpool in ASP.NET?

I'm interested in Webrole and Worker-only implementations.

**Source:**

- Whitepaper [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19222)  (see page 58)
- A blog [Overriding Stream Asynchrony](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/06/10291582.aspx)

Comment: This might be a good use case for TPL Dataflow, which is included in .Net 4.5 and uses `async`/`await`. With it, you could perform each of the steps in parallel, using your cores efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

TPL or async/await are purely framework constructs. They "simply" make easier the same tasks you would do if you managed threads or used asynchronous calls by hand. There is no need to integrate anything with Azure storage.

TPL and the async/await functionality built on top of it, schedule work using a scheduler. The default scheduler uses the [4.0 ThreadPool](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx) using work-stealing techniques. This means that you don't have to worry about scheduling work to the ThreadPool.

As for speeding up stream operations, the performance increase comes from breaking up a complex stream operation and creating a pipeline of steps. Each step executes asynchronously, potentially using a separate core or hyperthread, if one is available. This allows IO-bound operations to run in parallel with CPU-bound operations.

In your example, the TransforStream copies blocks asynchronously from the input stream to the encryptor and then the compressor. This allows each step to execute asynchronously, as fast as possible: the input stream keeps reading from disk while the compressor and encryptor process data in memory.

As for Windows Azure storage performance, the concerns are not TPL-specific. You should note that each partition or blob can handle a maximum of IO operations. The best option is to partition your data so that you can send parallel requests to different partitions. You will have to use a partitioning scheme that does not create "hot" partitions. 
While partitioning is important for all Azure applications, the use of asynchronous operations means that a lot more IO requests are executed for each web request.

In answer to your question, the use of TPL on Azure is no different than any other application.

Comment: Assuming that my blob is on multiple containers/partitions... I'm hoping someone may have attempted this, and can share the results.

Comment: The point is that you are asking two almost unrelated questions. Parallel stream processing has nothing to do with Azure storage, while Azure storage performance has nothing to do with the technology you use to make requests in parallel. Apart from that, it is standard procedure to make long running calls asynchronously and spread the load to as many partitions as possible.